Convert mixed Unicode Numbers/Values/Strings (The whole Line contains also string) to a String
I have a line "Example: \u09b8\u09be\u09b0\u09cd\u09ac\u09bf\u09df\u09be\u09df \u0993\u09df\u09be\u09b0\u09cd\u0995\u09aa\u09be\u09b0\u09ae\u09bf\u099f \u09ad\u09bf\u09b8\u09be,"
What I want to, get a string from this line as follows : "Example: সার্বিয়ায় ওয়ার্কপারমিট ভিসা,"
I assume that it could be found by Integer.parseInt() method, then  what will be the procedure?

It seems likely that this is JSON - so just use a JSON parser, which should handle the escape sequences for you.

It already IS a String (Unicode escaped format). Did the double quote characters at each end not give you a clue to that fact?

Jon Skeet, may elaborate as a answer please ?

What's there to elaborate? Is this JSON or not?

Does this answer your question? Convert escaped Unicode character back to actual character

@BasilBourque Edited.

@Sören thanks for the link, but there is only one character, But I have many lines.

Edit your Question to explain this text is being retrieved from a database. Don’t make us readers wade through your Comments to understand your Question.

Java compiler automatically unescapes
Your input is a String literal containing escaped Unicode code point numbers. This syntax is understood directly by the Java compiler.
So there is no need to unescape.
String input = "ইউরোপের\u09b8\u09be\u09b0\u09cd\u09ac\u09bf\u09df\u09be\u09df \u0993\u09df\u09be\u09b0\u09cd\u0995\u09aa\u09be\u09b0\u09ae\u09bf\u099f \u09ad\u09bf\u09b8\u09be," ;
System.out.println( input ) ;

See this code run at Ideone.com.

ইউরোপেরসার্বিয়ায় ওয়ার্কপারমিট ভিসা,

Perhaps you want to generate Java source code without the escapes. That is legitimate as the Java language fully supports Unicode characters in source code.
We can add a double-quote character to each end of your string. Since Java syntax uses the double-quote character, we must escape like this: "\"".
// Generate source code. 
String sourceCode = "\"" + input +  "\"" ;
System.out.println( sourceCode ) ;


"ইউরোপেরসার্বিয়ায় ওয়ার্কপারমিট ভিসা,"


Though I have Edited the example in  My question, You are right, Please Edit the example Also in your answer.

If my comment HERE is correct then this approach is simpler:
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\\\u[0-9a-f]{4}").matcher(s);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while (m.find()) {
            m.appendReplacement(sb, Character.toString(Integer.parseInt(m.group(), 16)));
        }
        m.appendTail(sb);
        System.out.println(sb.toString());


Error : {( Integer.parseInt(m.group(), 16)) }Required type: char Provided: int, And Error { m.appendTail(sb);} Required type: StringBuffer Provided: StringBuilder

Looks like your Android has very old language support if you're getting that sort of error

The main approach for this method is
int hexValue = Integer.parseInt(letter, 16);

So, I have found the result with following functions :
public static  String unicodeStringToString(String unicode){
        System.out.println("ddd first Response 3:unicode " + unicode);

        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(unicode)){
            return  "";
        }

        StringBuilder txt = new StringBuilder();

        String [] words = unicode.split(" ");
        for (String word: words){
            if(word.contains("\\u")) {
                System.out.println("ddd first Response 4:word " + word);
                word = word.replace("\\", "");
                String[] letters = word.split("u");
                for (String letter : letters) {
                    System.out.println("ddd first Response 5:letter " + letter);
                    if(letter.contains(",")) {
                        letter= letter.replace(",", "");
                        String s = unicodeNumberToString(letter);
                        txt.append(s);
                        txt.append(",");
                    }else {
                        String s = unicodeNumberToString(letter);
                        txt.append(s);
                    }
                    txt.append(" ");
                }
            }else {
                txt.append(word);
                txt.append(" ");
            }

        }

        return txt.toString();

        // uses : textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(unicodeStringToString(unicode)));

    }

public static  String unicodeNumberToString(String letter){
        

        if(isInteger(letter)) {
            int hexValue = 0;
            try {
                hexValue = Integer.parseInt(letter, 16);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            letter = String.valueOf(((char) hexValue));
        }
        return  letter ;
    }

public static boolean isInteger(String s) {
        try {
            Integer.parseInt(s);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("integer Problem: isInteger:  "+e.toString());
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }


Could you please explain (a) What problem this code is supposed to solve (I don't think there is one, see comment by g00se) and (b) how it does that?

@Sören, I think that the example is wrong and that the OP somehow has a String containing literal escapes. If that's the case then it should have stated: "ইউরোপের\\u09b8\\u09be..."

@g00se yeah, maybe. I just don't like to guess like that.

@g00se, this string comes from mySql database as it is "ইউরোপের\u09b8\u09be\u09b0\u09cd\u09ac\u09bf\u09df\u09be\u09df \u0993\u09df\u09be\u09b0\u09cd\u0995\u09aa\u09be\u09b0\u09ae\u09bf\u099f \u09ad\u09bf\u09b8\u09be,"

What is the wrong? It works for me!

@g00se, this string comes from mySql database as it is That's definitely odd. Why would only part of the string be shown as Unicode-escaped?

@g00se, I have Edited. Thanks.
